# Latexpand not finding include and input files

Tags: subfiles

Using Latexpand script, I am trying to compile the multiple latex files. But Latexpand is not finding the include and input files, whereas all the files are located at the specified locations. It says Warning: File not found. I have attached a snapshot for your reference.

Am i missing something??

[image: Error Snapshot]

Comment: I have never used it but I would guess it is confused by the windows path on the command line, try cd to the sample/original directory and then a command line of `perl latexpand.pl  thesis.tex`

Comment: You nailed it right. Changed the path in command line, also placed the script file in the Tex files folder and it worked like a charm :)

NB: Wanted to but couldn't figure out for marking your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is confused by the windows path on the command line, try cd to the `sample/original` directory and then a command line of

```
perl latexpand.pl thesis.tex
```